# Regarding Neoload 5.0.2

Tags: neoload

I'm getting an error msg "Load Generator Unavailable" pop up evry 2 iterations when I run the script via check virtual user.Closing and reopeing Neoload solves the issue.Could any of you please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is a common issue with Neoload across versions, we have seen this across all of our windows installations where we run with localhost as a load generator or when we run with stand-alone generators.  Most of the time a stop and restart of the load generators and load controllers will solve this issue.  On more rare occasions a complete restart of the controller server needs to happen.  This is issue is appearing in the latest version as of the date of my response.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have this problem. I just needed to restart my load generator. All I did was ssh into my load generator that was acting up. Then ran `sudo –u neoload /opt/neoload/bin/LoadGeneratorAgent stop` then after that I would run `sudo –u neoload /opt/neoload/bin/LoadGeneratorAgent start &` Exit and restart neoload and I stopped having the problem. You will just replace the path with your own. This is for external load generators not local host generators.